# Is the Riemann zeta function surjective?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Does the function $\zeta(s)$ attain all complex values?

Comment: The Little Picard Theorem does not apply because $\zeta$ is not entire.

Comment: Still $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is an entire function. Also, necessarily $\zeta(s)$ has an essential singularity in $\infty$, so I guess $\zeta(s)$ attains every complex value _except possibly one_ in every (punctured) neighborhood of $\infty$?

Comment: What about that one value?

Comment: You should state that you later asked the same question on Math Overflow. And got an answer! Link to thread there: [Is the Riemann zeta function surjective?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300466/)